# When I try to close ssh2 connection, no response back

Tags: php, ssh2-sftp, ssh2

I wrote a php script to execute locally, on an apache server with php7.3, doing the following:

1. access server via ssh2
2. check if a file exists
3. close connection
4. printing json data object as a response.

script works without problems except for closing connection. if I add ssh2_disconnect function, no response comes back. What am I missing?
Here is my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $config = ["server"=>"10.1.201.1","port"=>"22","user"=>"root","password"=>"root","folder"=>"/"];
    $files = ["file1.pdf","file2.pdf"];
    $result = [];
    $ftpConnect = ssh2_connect($config['server'],$config['port']);
        ssh2_auth_password($ftpConnect,$config['user'],$config['password']);
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($ftpConnect);

foreach ($files as $file){
    $fileExists = file_exists("ssh2.sftp://". intval($sftp) . $config['folder'] . $file);
        if($fileExists){
            $result[$file]= ["status"=>"Found"];
        }else $result[$file]= ["status"=>"Not found"];
}
//ssh2_disconnect($ftpConnect); only if uncommented, script wouldn't work
header('content-type:text/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Hope those are fake credentials

Comment: sure they are :)

Comment: Even if they weren't you're not in his lan :)). You don't know who `10.1.201.1` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be version dependant. `ssh2_disconnect` is the only function you use to be available with `PECL ssh2 >= 1.0` all the other `ssh2` functions are available for `PECL ssh2 >= 0.9.0.` 
The following comment let us think php >= 7 is also needed.

http://php.net/manual/function.ssh2-disconnect.php#123413

Here is how he suggest to close the connexion without `ssh2_disconnect` available :

```
$session = null; unset($session); // close connection
```

Comment: if so, shouldn't I get an error back? something like error code and 'undefined function'? because no response is showing at all.

Comment: I tested the function existence by if(function_exists('ssh2_disconnect')) echo '1'; and it succeeded.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but can't. Without ssh2_disconnect everything is fine and when I uncomment it the output is the following :
{"file1.pdf":{"status":"Not found"},"file2.pdf":{"status":"Not found"}}php: channel.c:2466: _libssh2_channel_free: Assertion `session' failed.
Abandon (core dumped)

Comment: The function may be buggy. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73438&edit=1

Comment: thank you for your time, yes probably it is a bug and there for unset still the safer method :)

Comment: ssh2 is unstable: https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2 version 1.2 - beta (2019-09-18). After change `ssh2_disconnect()` to `unset` my script was executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems with more recent implementations we could successfully close the connection from SFTP with the ssh2-disconnect

So for anyone reading this, I think it's the best solution now.

Sample from the SFTP server logs:

client at xxx sent SSH_DISCONNECT message: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) (Application disconnected)

(Also no errors when transferring files)